# what is the probability that drug was effective for this person knowing the Poisson distribution of the number of time that person get sick

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, bayes-theorem

> The number of colds person gets in a year has ${\rm Poisson}(3)$ distribution. A new drug lower it to ${\rm Poisson}(.75)$ and is effective for $8$ out of $10$ people. The entire population was given the drug. One person was selected at random from the population and was found to have $1$ cold during the year. What is the probability that the drug was effective for this person?

Assuming $A$ is having $1$ cold per year and $B$ the drug is effective.

By knowing $P(B) = 8/10$ and finding the probability of having 1 cold/year before and after the drug. $P(A|B) = \exp(-.75)(.75)=.354275$ and $P(A|B^{c}) = exp(-3)(3)= .14936$, I can almost use the Bayes' theorem to find the $P(B|A)$ which is the probability the drug being effective knowing the person have been chosen had only 1 cold.

$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^{c})P(B^{c})}$.

I still miss a part of the equation $P(B^{c})$ if my assumption was correct.

Comment: If you know $P(B)$ then you can easily find $P(B^c)$ ...

Comment: if you mean $1-P(B) = .2$ I did try this assumption even thought I don't see it logical to assume not applying the drugs having complementing of applying the drug. the result was $.86443$ while the book says $.905$

Comment: You mean $P(A\mid B^c)=\exp(-3)\cdot 3$ and not (-3).

Comment: it was type thanks. $P(A|B^{c}) = exp(-3)(3)$

Comment: It is not only a typo: $\exp(-3)3=0.149$ not $0.222$. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in $$P(A\mid B^c)=\exp(-3)3=0.149\neq 0.22245$$ as you have it. So this is only a calculation mistake, rest including $P(B^c)=0.2$, is correct. To see this note that there are only two outcomes (as defined):

1. $B:$ the drug is effective,
2. $C:$ the drug is not effective.

These are by their definition complementary. $B$ occurs or $C$ occurs. So, it must be that $P(B)=1-P(C)$ (actually $C$ stands for $B^c$ here).

Comment: It was my mistake thanks. the answer is correct now. I solved it this way. but I'm not convinced about applying the rule $1−P(B)$. I don't see it logical

Comment: @Feras. Ok see my edit. Why don't you see it logical?

Comment: got it. to clear it more. when the drug is effective it has .8 probability while .2 being not effective. I was missing this part. Not being effective $=$ not applying the drug

Comment: You mean in your last sentence: Not being effective *is not the same* as not applying the drug. Because Not being effective = not applying the drug does not make sense to me.

Comment: probability of not being effective is equal to the case before applying the drug. since we already used $P(A|B^{c})$ as the case of having one cold before applying the drug and multiply by $P(B^{c})$ not being effective.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.